# julia dispatch on parametric abstract type

Tags: types, julia

Considering the following setup

```
abstract AbstractShape
type Shape_1 <: AbstractShape end
type Shape_2 <: AbstractShape end
type Shape_3 <: AbstractShape end

abstract AbstractElement{S<:AbstractShape}
type Element_1{S} <: AbstractElement{S} end
type Element_2{S} <: AbstractElement{S} end
#...
type Element_n{S} <: AbstractElement{S} end
```

I would like to retrieve the shape type parameter S of each concrete element type, e.g.

```
shape(::Type{Element_1{Shape_3}}) = Shape_3
```

using something like

```
shape{S}(::Type{AbstractElement{S}}) = S
```

so I don't have to write a `shape` function for each element type.

Is this possible and how would I do that?
(Thanks for your help!)

Comment: `Type` is a parametric type which is invariant.  you can use `shape{S, E<:AbstractElement{S}}(::Type{E}) = S` in Julia-v0.6.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Is there a way to work around this in julia.v0.5?

Comment: `shape{S<:AbstractElement}(::Type{S}) = S.parameters[1]` will do the trick, but I guess there's a better way.

Comment: It's triangular dispatch. Use @Gnimuc's workaround on v0.5, but v0.6 will have the dispatch approach work.

Answer (score 4):

I would not advise Gnimuc's workaround in 0.5, as it would fail if the concrete `Element_n`s did not all have the same kind; i.e. if perhaps `Element_4{N,S} <: AbstractElement{S}`.

Instead a better workaround is the trick used by `eltype` in 0.5; that is

```
shape{S<:AbstractShape}(::Type{AbstractElement{S}}) = S
shape{T<:AbstractElement}(::Type{T}) = shape(supertype(T))
```

On 0.6, of course, you may simply write the dispatch:

```
(shape(::Type{T}) where T <: AbstractElement{S} where S <: AbstractShape) = S
```